# Want help making a command output as a variable in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

so I want to make a battery widget for my Macbook using Ubersicht, and while I have that, I want it so that it can be different colors at different battery percentages. Right now, the code looks like this:

```
command: "pmset -g batt | grep -o '[0-9]*%'"

refreshFrequency: 60000

style: """
  bottom: 632px
  left: 10px
  color: #fff
  font-family: Helvetica Neue

  div
    display: block
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(#000, 0.5)
    font-size: 60px
    font-weight: 100
    background: rgba(#070, .3)
    position: absolute
    margin-bottom: 5px
    border-radius: 10px
    padding 3px 5px 3px


"""


render: -> """
  <div class='battery'></div>
"""

update: (output, domEl) ->
  $(domEl).find('.battery').html(output)
```

How would I do this so that it would change colors? I already tried it so that it was this:

```
command: "pmset -g batt | grep -o '[0-9]*%'"
batteryPercent = command: "pmset -g batt | grep -o '[0-9]*%'"

refreshFrequency: 60000

batteryColor = '#070' if batteryPercent >= 60%
batteryColor = '#770' batteryPercent < 60%
batteryColor = '#700' if batteryPercent <= 30%

...

background: rgba(#{batteryColor}, .3)
```

That, however, gives me this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: batteryPercent
```

Could you please help me with this? I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me with this, as I have been searching for a solution for two whole days now.

Comment: there's not enough information here. Can you show the full file and the full error?

Comment: This IS the full file and the full error. If it was longer, I would have still posted the whole thing here.

Comment: `batteryPercent = command: "pmset -g batt | grep -o '[0-9]*%'"` makes `batteryPercent` a hash. Then you say `batteryPercent >= 60%` which is wrong for a number of reasons. `60%` is not a valid term, and even if it was a number, it shouldn't be compared with a hash.  `batteryPercent.command` could be interpreted as a shell command with the use of `execSync` or something. Anyway, I don't think the code you've shown would raise the error you show, so I would bet that this isn't the most recently version of the code. Perhaps you could revise the question with your most recent code.